# Change variable value in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using a variable 'f' in a Simulink system. At first 'f' is initialized through command prompt. Can I change this value 'f' in Simulink during simulation?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways this might be done - the best isn't clear based on what you've said so far.

One solution is the following:

Let's assume you have a `Gain` block where the value of the gain has been specified as the variable `f` which has been given a value in the MATLAB Workspace.  After the simulation has started you can do,

```
>> f = your_new_value_for_f;
>> set_param('the_name_of_the_gain_block','Gain','f');
```

The above will force Simulink to look in the Workspace for the new value of `f` when you press *return*.

For other blocks you need to determine the name of the appropriate block parameter.  See the doc for `set_param` for more information.